# Store Angular Type<any> in Array

Tags: angular, typescript

My goal is to store component references, like its done in Angular routes, but in my own service, e.g.

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteInjectorService {

    getRoutes() {
        return [
            { path: ['event-list'], component: EventListPageComponent },
            { path: ['404'], component: NoContentComponent },
            { path: ['offer'], component: OfferPageComponent },
        ];
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I inject RouteInjectorService into any component, I get circular dependency error:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for EventListPageComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
```

Where **?** is my RouteInjectorService. 
My guess is that

```
{ path: ['event-list'], component: EventListPageComponent }
```

tries to construct component with all its deps, creating loop: EventListPageComponent <- RouteInjectorService <- EventListPageComponent <- ...

Storing components in separate const results in same error. My thought is that I should include some kind of loading guard or something. Moreover, placing getRoutes() into any component like AppComponent's ngOnInit() works fine. Or, placing

```
constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => RouteInjectorService))private router: RouteInjectorService
) {}
```

into component is working, but placing forwardRef into all those components, which require RouteInjectorService is quite a pain. I wonder if there is a better way.

So question is, how I can store components in array without their excess initialization, like its done in Angular router system?

Comment: You should show more of your architecture. Where/how do you provide this service? How do you inject and use it? What's the error text? Do the routes work when you use them the regular way?

Comment: I wouldn´t make that injectable. You should create a constants.ts file with _export const ROUTES = [...]_ then you should be able to used everywhere with _import {ROUTES} from 'constants';_

Comment: @kimy82 To be fair, I tried several ways, and started just like you said.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Updated question a bit. At the time I add dependency to any of these component constructor, I receive this error. Same goes if I provide RouteInjectorService with Injector.get(). I dont use regular Angular route system, since it doesn't satisfies my objectives, so i'm not dealing with it right now.